# Compatibility issue for IE8 and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

Currently, my web application is working on IE7 compatibility mode, i.e. I am using the following meta tag.

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"
```

But now I would like to unsupport IE7 and use IE8, IE9 compatibility mode.

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=9"
```

Doing so, however, wrecks my UI and I also start to get the following error.

> type error object doesn't support this property or method `__defineGetter__`

Also, I found the following link at IE support.

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/757992/implement-object-prototype-definegetter-and-object-prototype-definesetter-for-compatibility

Is there any other way i can support IE8 and IE9?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following css class to ur page . I have encountered the same issue and got fixed after adding this ..

```
 /* For modern browsers */.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after
        {
            content: "";
            display: table;
        }
        .clearfix:after
        {
            clear: both;
        }
        /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */.clearfix
        {
            zoom: 1;
        }
```